# jquery ajax posting directory

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post an ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'directory/file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:   'param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2,
            success: function(response){
                $('#content').html(response);
            }
});
```

The POST request does not work when I use this code snippet, but if I move the file up one directory and use:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:   'param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2,
            success: function(response){
                $('#content').html(response);
            }
});
```

Then it magically works.

I have tried:

/directory/file.php and fullpath/directory/file.php

I also included the full path when I moved it up one directory and it still worked.

I must be over looking something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong, but have you tried adding ../../ or ../ or / before the url?

Comment: at which directory is the file.php?

Comment: It's in the root of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with this block of code, so the
problem must be elsewhere.  When working on AJAX, if something
isn't working right, here's the set of steps I generally take to
figure out where the problem is.  A lot of this is rather
obvious, but I've found that taking nothing for granted and
systematically verifying each in turn will generally help me
resolve the issue quickly.  Finally, I'll generally reference
using Firebug because that's my tool of choice, but you could
accomplish most of this with other tools just as easily.

First, when working with AJAX code, I always have Firebug open.
Load the page, and make sure there are no JavaScript syntax
errors on the page itself that may be preventing event handlers
from being wired, etc.

Next, I'd modify the code you gave to be the following:

```
alert('Running AJAX request');
$.ajax({
            url: 'directory/file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:   'param1=' + param1 + '¶m2=' + param2,
            success: function(response){
                alert('Response received: ' + response);
                $('#content').html(response);
                alert('Document modified.');
            },
            error: function(req) {
                alert('Error: ' + req.status);
            }
});
```

Now, when you trigger your AJAX request, you should get plenty of
information that'll tell you where in the process something got
tripped up.

If you don't see 'Running AJAX request,' check the event handlers
that are supposed to be triggering your request.  If you see
'Error: ,' then verify that the request URL was as you expected
and that manually browsing to that URL gives the expected result.

If you see 'Response received: ', but the response text isn't
what you expect, again, try browsing to the page manually in your
browser.  If there's a difference between what you see in the
browser and what the AJAX request is seeing, use Firebug's Net
tab to check for differences between the parameters your browser
and the AJAX request are sending (e.g. perhaps you need to append
a session identifier in the AJAX request).

If all of that works, but the document modification doesn't
happen as expected, then use Firebug's DOM tab to verify that
document IDs are matching between the DOM and the script, and
inspect the DOM to see what changes are actually happening as a
result of your $('#content').html(response) line.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently. After playing around using the recommended Firebug above (cheers, btw!), I realised that the problem lied in the .php file and not the in the javascript. When I moved the php-file one folder down, it was no longer referring to the same folders and files as it did one level up.

Hope this spares someone out there from the headache I've had the last few hours!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the "error"-callback of the $.ajax method and return the status code in it.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'directory/file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:   'param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2,
            success: function(response){
                $('#content').html(response);
            },
            error: function(req, status, error) {
                       window.alert( req + "\n" + status + "\n" + error );
                   }
});
```

There could be a problem with your chmod on that directory, which needs to be at least 755 (everything, but only group and owner can write). In that case, a 403-HTTP-Status-Code should be returned by jQuery.

This could help finding the mistake.

Comment: I am developing in Windows, so it is not a owner/group/other permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code using jquery 1.4.2 It worked fine. So except maybe you don't have access rights to that folder or you mixed up the directory structure one way or the other.

Try pasting the url in you $.ajax function in your browser and see if it works.

Cheers